# Non-unique results matching criteria for a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, criteria

I am using R to pull a set of rows from a data frame.  Many of the rows are pulled repeatedly.  The rows are chosen using two criteria.  Unfortunately the results are yielding a unique set of rows matching the criteria.  I shall demonstrate...

Given the data.frame:

```
a = data.frame(array(c(1,2,3,1,4,5,6,2,7,8,9,4), c(4,3)))
```

Which will look like:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
4  1  2  4
```

Lets suppose I wish to call upon `a` with two sets of criteria defined by arrays:

```
criteriaX1 = c(1,2,1,1,2)
criteriaX2 = c(4,5,4,2,5)
```

Then I would use this command:

```
a[ a$X1 %in% criteriaX1 & a$X2 %in% criteriaX2, ]
```

Hoping to get 5 rows like so (look @ criteriaX1 for the key, and read down X1. Should make sense if it didn't already):

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  1  4  7
4  1  2  4
5  2  5  8
```

But instead I just got this:

```
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  5  9
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with `%in%` defining Set Membership, but I'm not sure how to get around this without an obnoxious loop.  All assistance is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `criteriaX2` isn't really doing anything, so the naive solution is to use `match`:  `a[match(criteriaX1, a$X1),]`

Comment: What does it mean (in natural language, please) to add 3 to 'criteriaX1'?

Comment: I've modified " + 3 " to make it more clear, but it was just to make it so that it represented the values in the column `criteriaX2`.  Also, thank you Justin, `match` works under the condition you described however I mean for the condition to be unique across both columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a data.table equi-join:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(a)
b <- data.table(X1 = criteriaX1, X2 = criteriaX2)

setkey(a, X1, X2)
a[b]
#    X1 X2 X3
# 1:  1  4  7
# 2:  2  5  8
# 3:  1  4  7
# 4:  1  4  7
# 5:  2  5  8
```

Comment: I don't know if it's more or less confusing, but `b` can have columns  with different names: `b <- data.table(criteriaX1, criteriaX2)`.

Comment: Then do: `a[b[, list(X1 = criteriaX1, X2 = criteriaX2)]]`

Comment: Oh, I meant that the join doesn't care what the variables in b are named. It just takes them in order. (If b had a key, something different would happen, though.) A shorter, but probably more opaque approach would be `adt[J(criteriaX1,criteriaX2)]` (where `adt` is `data.table(a)`).

Comment: I'm tempted to reject my own method in favor of this one. It's very clean.  Thanks for the suggestion!